# Quais dicionários do português brasileiro são confiáveis?

Tags: gramática

Quando eu procuro por significado de palavras em português, não raro encontro vários sites que parecem usar dados baseados na opinião das pessoas, [como esse aqui](https://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br).

Quais critérios devo utilizar para julgar se o significado de uma palavra é, de fato, o que consta no site ? Devo cruzar a informação com outras fontes? Só posso confiar em informações de dicionários impressos?

Comment: Minhas recomendações: [**Dicio**](https://www.dicio.com.br/), [**VOLP**](http://www.academia.org.br/nossa-lingua/busca-no-vocabulario) e [**Priberam**](https://www.priberam.pt). O *VOLP* pertence à Academia Brasileira de Letras, infelizmente não funciona como um dicionário, mas sempre recorro para ele quando tenho uma dúvida sobre a morfologia ou existência de uma palavra.

Comment: Tem havido alguma discussão se perguntas deste tipo deveria estar aqui ou no meta, sem grande conclusão, creio. Eu uso coisas como o Dicionário Informal, que tu lincas, apenas como complemento. A primeira coisa que eu vejo são os dicionários "formais". Tens aqui no meta [uma pergunta e respostas sobre dicionários e português brasileiro](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304/quais-dicion%C3%A1rios-de-portugu%C3%AAs-brasileiro-s%C3%A3o-confi%C3%A1veis).

Comment: É valido ressaltar que o Dicio e Dicionário Informal não são produzidos por profissionais, ou seja, lexicógrafos e linguistas com uma sólida formação acadêmica. Logo, não se pode confiar completamente nas acepções apresentadas neles. Os dicionários impressos são, geralmente, mais confiáveis.

Answer (score 4):

Normalmente a busca por termos em dicionários impressos tem se tornado cada vez menos usuais. Porém, eles ainda são uma boa fonte de informações. Levando isso em consideração, uma boa dica seria utilizar os sites relacionados a estas publicações. A confiança em tais sites, guardadas as proporções, estão intrinsecamente relacionadas à confiança no produto impresso.

Confirmar em mais de um local a significância de um termo é um bom modelo de certificação. Em trabalhos acadêmicos, dependendo da instituição, é necessário fontes além de sites, e quando é possível referenciar sites, há uma gama limitada sobre quais são fontes confiáveis. Para a pesquisa por termos, o mesmo mecanismo pode e deve ser utilizado. Ou seja, encontrando a significância de um termo em um site, pode-se confirmar procurando em material impresso reconhecido.

Por exemplo: http://michaelis.uol.com.br Relacionado ao conhecido dicionário Michaelis. 
Outro bastante útil é o https://www.priberam.pt "Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa".

Vale lembrar que a lingua é viva e muitos dos falantes em uma determinada lingua acabam por ter contato com a evolução dos termos desta lingua. Significa dizer que ao se deparar com a busca por termos mais formais é quase certa a localização em algum destes sites citados acima. Já para termos provenientes da lingua coloquial ou menos preocupada com a estrutura formal, os sites com contribuições de usuários, embora menos confiáveis, podem levar a um primeiro entendimento de uma palavra comumente utilizada por nichos específicos ou menores da população falante naquela língua.

Answer (score 1):

@Paulostation respondendo sua pergunta. Os dicionários impressos são de fato a melhor fonte para procurar o significado das palavras. Pois foram feitos por uma equipe especializada em várias áreas da Letras. Ou seja, possuem muitos pesquisadores por detras Mestres e Doutores em Linguistica. Então o significado delas é mais consistente e preciso e sólido. Mas claro que todos os anos eles lançam sempre uma nova versão justamente para manterem-se atualizados. Porém, o resultado do trabalho deles é mais bem elaborado.

Eu recomendo sim ter um dicionario impresso como Houiass, Aurelio ou Michaelis. Porque você pode as vezes precisar para fazer um trabalho ou tirar dúvida. Alias, nem sempre é garantido que a energia eletrica ou a internet vão estar funcionando o tempo todo. Então é importante ter um dicionario bom e impresso.

Bom mas fora isso, infelizmente você vai ter que sempre recorrer para outras fontes como os dicionarios informais online. Que são feitos baseado em opiniões. A questão é que a "multidão" ou "povo", por exemplo com o passar do tempo que nao sabe o significado verdadeiro da palavra, passa a trata-la com outro significado e isso infelizmente pega e se torna um consenso sem as pessoas perceberem. Então infelizmente você sempre vai ter que ter este trabalho de cruzar as informações da fonte. O criterio a ser adotado é simples, você ficou dúvida ai voce vai no dicionario informal baseado em opinião e le o significado, para constatar se é aquilo mesmo o significado, só procurar o mesmo termo no dicionario impresso como Michaelis, Houiass ou Aurelio ou site destes. Mas se você quiser consultar 6 dicionarios isso depende muito de você, se vai sanar a sua dúvida. Agora em relação a confiar em dicionarios impressos, bom eles tambem possuem sua fonte online. Mas a diferença é que o impresso demora 1 ano para se atualizar e voce ter que comprar de novo. Mas como eles tem a versão online, eles estão sempre em atualização. Espero ter conseguido esclarecer sua dúvida. Claro que existem muitas discussões sobre isso, como etimologia da palavra que vão além de um entendimento de uma pessoa leiga no assunto. Que está somente restrito ao meio da pesquisa. Mas dentro do que te coloquei aqui é o suficiente para compreensão.

Comment: Existem vários dicionários *offline*, mas o problema da energia continua. Sobre os impressos, o dicionário Houaiss (*ISBN-10: 8573029633*) possuem 2048 páginas, não acho que alguém terá-lo a disposição a todo o momento. Ps.: A Academia Brasileira de Letras já fez elogios ao *Dicionário Priberam*.