# Somente “monólito” é aceita ou também "monolito"?

Tags: ortografia

Nota: sou do Brasil.

Alguns dicionários parecem aceitar somente “monólito”, entre eles o Aurélio. A enciclopédia Larousse Cultural que tenho em casa — publicada pelo jornal Folha de S. Paulo em [1998](https://www1.folha.uol.com.br/fsp/brasil/fc17059819.htm) — aceita ambas, “monólito” e “monolito”.

Nunca achei “monolito” errada, porque me lembro de tê-la lido assim em um ou mais lugares, talvez em 2001: Odisseia Espacial (nota: veriquei depois que minha cópia emprega "monólito", e isto somente em poucas passagens, então era difícil de lembrar corretamente); há também uma história antiga em quadrinhos publicada por aqui nos anos 80/90, cujo anúncio vi quando pequeno, chamada “A Vingança do Monolito Vivo”. Mas vejo o pessoal preferindo falar “monólito” em alguns lugares, como se fosse a única forma certa. “Monolito” seria, em geral, errada?

Comment: Isso me lembra da palavra “rúbrica”, que está incorreta, sendo a certa “rubrica”. Creio que seja o mesmo para “monolito”, mas não posso afirmar.

Comment: Eu falo "mônolito" kkk, mas não sei se é a forma certa de se pronunciar.

Comment: @LuizFelipe, não há uma forma correta de pronunciar, mas há uma forma correta de escrever.

Comment: @LuizFelipe Rapaz, você inventou uma nova sílaba tônica, a "proproparoxítona" 

Comment: @Piovezan, falando de modo prático, é melhor escrever “monólito”, já que “monolito” aparenta ser uma forma não aceita por muitos dicionários enquanto “monólito” está presente em todos os dicionários vistos por aqui.

Comment: @Schilive Certo, aceitei a primeira resposta dada.

Comment: Proparoxítonas 
**Todas as palavras proparoxítonas (aquelas cuja sílaba tônica é a antepenúltima) são acentuadas**: lúcido, século, próximo. Em parceria com a Câmara dos Deputados, o Senado realiza um programa de visitas guiadas ao Palácio do Congresso Nacional. https://www12.senado.leg.br/manualdecomunicacao/estilos/acentuacao

Comment: @Lambie a questão é indiferente quanto a essa regra, pois se "monolito" fosse correta seriam duas palavras com duas escritas distintas. Como em "sílaba", proparoxítona e portanto acentuada, e "[ele] silaba", terceira pessoa do presente do indicativo do verbo silabar, paroxítona não-acentuada, sendo ambas igualmente válidas.

Comment: Só que aqui não estamos falando de dois termos. Só de um. monolito não está no Priberam, um dos melhores dicionários.

Comment: @Lambie era justamente esta a questão. Em alguns lugares a palavra era usada/constava e por isso a dúvida. Quanto ao Priberam, ele aceita correções dos usuários, e não sei qual é a criteriosidade deles para tratar estas entradas, então não sei se dá para tomar como única referência para a questão. Vai que alguém cisma de pedir para inserir "monolito" lá porque consta numa enciclopédia brasileira e é usada em alguns outros lugares e eles aceitam.

Comment: A palavra tem só *dois sentidos relacionados**; a palavra é proparoxítona; então leva acento. Priberam: 1. Obra ou monumento feito de uma só pedra. 2. Pedra de grandes dimensões.
"monólito", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2021, https://dicionario.priberam.org/mon%C3%B3lito [consultado em 26-03-2023]. A Odisseia Espacial é uma tradução. A históira em quadrinhos tem  um erro.

Comment: @Lambie Vou aceitar o argumento. Complementando, acabo de verificar que a minha cópia da Odisseia Especial emprega "monólito", e apenas em poucas passagens, não estava me lembrando bem. Vou corrigir na pergunta.

Comment: O Piovezan, o monólito é "objeto" principal do filme. Várias sequências o mostra.

Comment: @Lambie Conheço o filme, mas não me recordo como era usado o termo nele, seja na versão dublada ou legendada. Falava do livro traduzido, que usa pouco o termo, referenciando o objeto de outras maneiras. No quadrinho entendo que se trata de um nome/título de personagem então deve ter havido uma tendência a persistir no erro de tradução a fim de não mudar o nome conhecido, mas acredito que este erro me marcou por ter sido provavelmente o primeiro lugar em que vi o termo sendo usado.

Comment: I think in the original it is called a monolith. Not sure if that helps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sempre falei "monolito", mas todos os dicionários que consultei (e.g., [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/monolito), [Houaiss](https://houaiss.uol.com.br/corporativo/apps/uol_www/v5-4/html/index.php#4), [Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/monolito), [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/monolito)) listam apenas "monólito", que tomo como sendo portanto a única forma aceita, ao menos na linguagem culta (e o uso de "monolito" por algumas publicações, como a [BBC em português](https://www.bbc.com/portuguese/geral-55063263), seria por erro).

Incidentalmente, provavelmente seu uso para a notícia *linkada* acima é questionável, dado que o objeto encontrado era de metal, enquanto "monolitos" são feitos de pedra.

Comment: No Michaelis online também é só monólito. Como anda a questão de se dar preferência a dicionários impressos? A meu ver essa questão é como gramáticos, mesmo que se tenha um certo consenso sobre algum ponto ainda assim alguns aceitam os dissidentes. Temos no site consenso sobre a questão do consenso?

Comment: @Piovezan, creio que não sejam os gramáticos quem aceitam as palavras. Penso que são ou os redatores do dicionário ou os lexicógrafos.

Comment: @Schilive Olá Schilive, quis dizer que a questão de consenso entre dicionários é semelhante à de consenso entre regras gramaticais em diferentes gramáticas (lembrando minha ótima professora de Português do colegial que dizia "De acordo com Hildebrando... já o Rocha Lima... no caso do Cegalla, que é mais acessível, porém menos tal qualidade... já Celso Cunha...").

Comment: @Piovezan Dicionários de acesso online aberto oferecem vantagens óbvias, mas não há restrição alguma - o que importa é a qualidade da fonte, seja ela online ou não.

Comment: @stafusa A minha dúvida vem daqui: https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/5262/1096

Comment: @Piovezan, entendo, e acho que a discussão na pergunta que você menciona é representativa: o que importa é a qualidade da fonte, mas quem julga essa qualidade? A vantagem dos impressos é terem passado pelo menos pelo crivo de uma editora, mas felizmente vários têm suas versões online (como o Houaiss e o Priberam).

Comment: Certo, então para não desmerecer os online (que supostamente ganham inclusive em recenticidade) dei meu +1 para a resposta. Mas deixo a pergunta aberta a eventuais citações de dicionários impressos dissidentes a essa provável norma.

Answer (score 4):

Só para somar àqueles que informam que *monolito* não é válida na norma culta, procurei no [Vocabulário Ortográfico da Língua Portuguesa](https://www.academia.org.br/nossa-lingua/busca-no-vocabulario) e não encontrei *monolito* lá.

Naturalmente, quem não respeitar a norma culta pode continuar a usar "monolito" paroxítona, e não "monólito" proparoxítona.

Mas pode ter problemas em documentos oficiais ou acadêmicos.

Comment: Exatamente isso.

Answer (score 2):

Vejam também: monócito, monóculo, monómero, monólogo.  Contudo: monopólio, mononuclear, monociclo, monopé.

A [regra geral](http://cvc.instituto-camoes.pt/cpp/acessibilidade/capitulo5_1.html) é *acento tónico na última vogal do radical*.

Claramente, "mono" não é o radical de "monólito", que é uma excepção (esdrúxula).

Vejam também: quilómetro, quilograma.

Interessante: o Instituto Camões admite ambos "logótipo" e "logotipo".

"Monólito, quilómetro, logótipo" só existem por tradição.  Já o Castelhano uso "monolito".

Comment: Um aparte: você citou monómero, mas e monômero? Se não me falha a memória já vi esse termo (português do Brasil), em oposição a polímero. Aproveitando, também telômero, quilômetro. Refere-se então ao português de Portugal?

Comment: @Piovezan, lembra-te que houve o acordo ortográfico: se uma palavra está correta na ortografia portuguesa, está na brasileira, e vice-versa.

Comment: @Schilive Ah, não sabia que se tinha unificado assim a ortografia. Obrigado por lembrar.

Comment: NOVO ACORDO ORTOGRÁFICO XI-3 Levam acento agudo ou acento circunflexo as palavras proparoxítonas, reais ou aparentes, cujas vogais tónicas/tônicas grafadas e ou o estão em final de sílaba e são seguidas das consoantes nasais grafadas m ou n, conforme o seu timbre é, respetivamente, aberto ou fechado nas pronúncias cultas da língua: académico/acadêmico, anatómico/anatômico, cénico/cênico, cómodo/cômodo, fenómeno/ fenômeno, género/gênero, topónimo/topônimo; Amazónia/Amazônia, António/Antônio, blasfémia/blasfêmia, fémea/fêmea, gémeo/gêmeo, génio/gênio, ténue/tênue.

Comment: Pierre, não ficou completamente claro para mim: então "monolito", sem acento, seria correto também?

Comment: Acho que não. __